# Tradução de nomes próprios no Português de Portugal

Tags: uso-de-palavras, português-europeu

Recentemente ouvi uma entrevista no rádio sobre diferenças entre o PT-BR e o PT-PT. Em certo ponto chegou-se ao assunto de que os portugueses têm tendência a traduzir estrangeirismos (p. ex. *mouse* virou *rato*). Até aí nenhuma novidade.

O que me chamou a atenção foi que o entrevistado disse que em Portugal traduz-se, inclusive, nomes próprios e deu como exemplo a rainha *Elizabeth* da Inglaterra e seu filho, o príncipe *Charles*. Segundo o entrevistado em Portugal ela é conhecida como Rainha *Isabel* e seu filho como Príncipe *Carlos*.

É real este costume de traduzir nomes próprios em geral em Portugal? E no caso específico dos monarcas ingleses, como são conhecidos pelos portugueses?

Comment: "ordernador"? Não estarás a confundir com o espanhol? Nunca ouvi tal coisa em Portugal, embora o dicionário registe a palavra.

Comment: @Artefacto, Olha, pelo que me lembro foi esse o exemplo usado no programa, mas não tenho certeza. Vou ver se acho uma gravação do programa para verificar. De qualquer sorte, o foco da questão é na tradução Elizabeth --> Isabel e Charles --> Carlos.

Comment: Mas eu confirmo: nunca ouvi *ordenador* em Portugal. Quanto à realeza, sim: rainha isabel II e príncipe Carlos. O pessoal, quando começa a apontar diferenças entre Portugal e Brasil, por vezes entusiasma-se.

Comment: Confirmado também nunca ouvi isso. Já agora não seria "*mouse* virou rato, *computer* virou ordenador"?

Comment: @JorgeB., Pode ser, mas eu escrevi _mouse_ e _computador_ fazendo a comparação entre PT-BR e PT-PT e não entre EN-US e PT-PT. Se for consenso que fica mais claro da maneira que disseste, posso (ou podes) editar a questão.

Comment: @gmauch é só a concordância de "os portugueses têm tendência a traduzir estrangeirismos" e os exemplos disso.

Comment: @Artefacto e Jorge B. removi a menção à "ordenador" visando clareza.

Comment: Embora eu seja brasileiro de nascimento, posso responder que sim: a rainha Elizabeth, o príncipe Charles e a princesa Margareth, em Portugal, são chamados de rainha Isabel, príncipe Carlos e a princesa Margarida.  Outros nomes próprios, de localidades, também são traduzidos, ou melhor, modificados ao sabor da língua: Stuttgart é Estugarda, Cameroun é a República dos Camarões, e assim vai.  Aqui no Brasil chamamos a cidade alemã de  Stuttgart, embora façamos uma "tradução" de München e outras cidades.  Também usamos "Camarões" mas isso deve ter sido influência Portuguesa durante a colonização.

Comment: ps. Os camaronenses parecem não gostar dessa tradução.  Quando jogaram contra o Brasil em uma das Copas, nossos jogadores disseram que iriam comer camarão no dia do jogo.  Os camaronenses não entenderam a piada e, quando explicada, responderam que o nome do país deles nada tem a ver com camarões.

Comment: @Centaurus, bem lembrado sobre os nomes de localidades. Uma que sempre me intrigou é a cidade de _Den Haag_ na Holanda (Netherlands) sede do Tribunal Penal Internacional. No Brasil ela é conhecida como _Haia_. Ainda que _den_ seja o artigo, acho uma tradução com pouca relação com o original.

Comment: @gmauch   E eu nem sabia que o nome é Den Haag.  A minha opinião é que os povos deveriam tentar conservar os nomes dos outros países o mais próximo daquilo que os nativos chamam seu país.  Porque não usar Confederação Helvética (ou "Confederação Suissa"), Magyarorzag (ou algo próximo de como é pronunciada em Húngaro), Sverige, Norge,  No caso de países onde é possível traduzir o nome, melhor então traduzir (United Kingdom, United Arab Emirates, New Zealand, etc)

Comment: @Centaurus [Uma pergunta relacionada](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/4175).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Os nomes próprios dos monarcas, faraós e czares estrangeiros são praticamente todos traduzidos, pelo menos aqueles que já entraram, há muito tempo, na variante europeia da Língua Portuguesa. É o caso de Eduardo, Isabel, Luís, Catarina, Carlos Magno, Napoleão, Balduíno, Gustavo, Jorge,  Maximiliano e [Ulrica Leonor](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulrica_Leonor_da_Su%C3%A9cia), [Faiçal](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faisal_II_do_Iraque) (ou Faisal). Dos não traduzidos, refiro os de [Haakon](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haakon,_o_Vermelho) (ou Haquino) e [Mohammad Ali Shah Qajar](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohammad_Ali_Shah_Qajar).

Quanto aos nomes próprios de Presidentes, Primeiros-Ministros e Chanceleres não são habitualmente traduzidos, em Portugal.

Sobre outros nomes próprios, a tendência é para os não traduzir: John, Mary, Madeleine.

Finalmente, em Portugal, traduzem-se os nomes dos [monarcas britânicos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_monarcas_brit%C3%A2nicos). Já os dos seus familiares podem ser traduzidos (Ana, em vez de Anne) ou não (William, em vez de Guilherme).

De forma similar, os nomes bíblicos e dos Papas, cada país utiliza a sua própria tradução, por exemplo: Madalena, Mateus, João, Bento, Francisco, etc.

Comment: Fiquei com um "porquê" preso na cabeça. Haverá alguma razão conhecida para essa tradução **só** de nomes de monarcas e chefes de estado? Será por serem nomes estabelecidos em tempos mais nacionalistas? Será simplesmente tradição histórica?

Comment: @ANeves Os nomes próprios dos Chefes de Estado que são ou foram Presidentes, como George W. Bush e François Mitterand  não se traduzem. Quanto à razão pela qual os que indiquei se traduzem só posso especular,  mas sou levado a pensar que a principal seja uma tradição histórica.

Answer (score 8):

Com reis e príncipes costuma traduzir-se, desde que o nome seja facilmente traduzível. Vê [aqui](https://gist.github.com/cataphract/0a21837d75214322da5c) a distribuição no CETEMPúblico.

"Elizabeth" e "Charles" são facilmente traduzidos, por isso domina a forma portuguesa. Quando passamos "William" temos já uma distribuição equilibrada entre o original e "Guilherme" e por fim há nomes que não são traduzidos de todo como "Hussein".

Com outras celebridades, costuma usar-se o primeiro e último nome, e não traduzir nenhum deles.

Answer (score 0):

Basta tentar digitar o nome de uma cidade no Wikipedia.  Aparecerão coisas bizarras para um brasileiro.  O Google Maps contém coisas como "Oxónia" no lugar de Oxford (esse é um caso extremo, mas também há Estugarda, Rossilhão, Perpinhão, Bona etc.) Praticamente todas as cidades cujos nomes nós brasileiros não traduzimos são convertidos para uma versão lusitana pelos sites mais conhecidos da internet.  Uma vez ouvi Mario Soares dando uma entrevista no qual se referia a Tony Blair como "Antonio Blair".  Não é, portanto, algo exclusivo dos monarcas.