# É costume traduzir siglas no Português de Portugal

Tags: uso-de-palavras, português-europeu, siglas

No Brasil é costume não traduzir palavras estrangeiras, ao contrário de Portugal, onde [palavras](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/582/por-que-o-idioma-portugu%C3%AAs-portugal-n%C3%A3o-aceita-muitas-palavras-estrangeiras-exe) e também [nomes próprios](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1435/tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-nomes-pr%C3%B3prios-no-portugu%C3%AAs-de-portugal) costumam ser traduzidos.

No Brasil costuma-se manter no original até mesmo [siglas](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/sigla). Sei que em Portugal é costumeiro traduzir palavras estrangeiras, mas o mesmo se aplica a siglas? Consigo pensar em um exemplo famoso dessa diferença, a doença conhecida como *AIDS* no Brasil é aportuguesada como *SIDA* em Portugal, mas o mesmo se aplica em outros casos?

Para que a questão não seja considerada muito ampla (siglas de maneira geral), enumero a seguir alguns exemplos de siglas não traduzidas no Brasil e gostaria de saber como são usadas em Portugal.

Na área de tecnologia:

- Laser (Light Amplification by Stimulated Emission of Radiation)
- Led (Light Emitting Diode)
- USB (Universal Serial Bus)

Na área automotiva:

- ABS (Antilock Braking System)
- EBD (Eletronic Brake-Force Distribuition)
- ESP (Eletronic Stability Program)

Órgão internacionais:

- UNICEF (United Nations Children's Fund)
- UNESCO (United Nations Educational, Scientific and Cultural Organization)
- FAO (Food and Agriculture Organization)

Comment: Related: [Porque é que são permitidas, no Brasil, palavras como “leiaute”?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/449/porque-%C3%A9-que-s%C3%A3o-permitidas-no-brasil-palavras-como-leiaute)

Comment: Related: [Por que o idioma português Portugal não aceita muitas palavras estrangeiras? Exemplo: Mouse](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/582/por-que-o-idioma-portugu%C3%AAs-portugal-n%C3%A3o-aceita-muitas-palavras-estrangeiras-exe)

Comment: As palavras laser e led já não são siglas, são substantivos por si próprias. Senão seriam LASER e LED.

Comment: Eu diria que depende, acho que no que toca a doenças a maioria delas é traduzida e usa-se a sigla da tradução. No que toca à tecnologia e organizações já não se traduzem. Embora nos usemos ONU [mas vocês também](http://nacoesunidas.org/). Dessas que estão ai acho que não traduzimos nenhuma.

Comment: Em inglês, e no [dicionário Priberam](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/led), LED é uma sigla, e é escrito "LED", não "led".

Comment: Gmauch, deves ter escrito um "não" a mais ou menos por engano: a respeito da tradução de palavras estrangeiras em Portugal, dizes no 1º parágrafo que é costume, e no 2º que não é. É capaz de haver uma tendência para exagerar as diferenças: vê a minha resposta a [esta pergunta sobre palavras estrangeiras](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/582/por-que-o-idioma-portugu%C3%AAs-portugal-n%C3%A3o-aceita-muitas-palavras-estrangeiras-exe)

Comment: @Jacinto Obrigado pela observação! Fiz a edição, mas sinta-se livre para fazê-la quando notares incoerências como esta!

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu ia colocar um exemplo mais atual, o grupo armando conhecido _Estado Islâmico_, que no Brasil vejo frequentemente ser chamado de ISIS (Islamic State of Syria and Iraq). Em Portugal usam qual expressão para referenciá-lo?

Comment: @gmauch tanto vês ISIS como vês EI (Estado Islâmico).

Comment: gmauch, Calculei que fosse essa a correção que quisesses fazer, mas não estava 100% seguro. Também concordo com o @JorgeB. que os teus exemplos são também assim em Portugal. E dizemos NATO, pelos vistos no Brasil é mais comum OTAN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As siglas e acrónimos apresentados na questão são também os usados em Portugal.

Na área da tecnologia parece-me ser uma tendência muito generalizada manter em Portugal as siglas e acrónimos originais. Posso acrescentar o CD (compact disk), PC (personal computer), DVD (digital video disk, funciona também em português), RAM (random-access memory), ROM (read-only memory), e coisas mais antigas como UHF (ultra-high frequency) ou TGV (train à grande vitesse, embora por extenso se diga *comboio de alta velocidade*).E ao contrário do afirmado na questão, usa-se também muitas palavras estrangeiras: air-bag, cockpit, laptop (concorre com portátil), browser, blogg, e-mail, site; e adaptações como net e mail.

Nos nomes de instituições usamos siglas e acrónimos baseados no nome inglês nuns casos, no nome em português noutros. Talvez uma coisa que influencie a escolha seja, para além de o nome por extenso ser ou não frequentemente usado, seja a facilidade de pronunciar o acrónimo. Por exemplo, nós dizemos NATO (Organização do Tratado do Atlântico Norte) possivelmente por ser mais eufónico que OTAN. Do mesmo modo dizemos EFTA e não AELC (Associação Europeia de Livre Comércio, da qual Portugal foi membro). Mas dizemos CEE (Comunidade Económica Europeia, predecessora da União Europeia).

Talvez isto tenha também contribuído para a preferência por SIDA: é, convenhamos, mais eufónico que AIDS

Comment: Não sei porquê mas esta resposta passou-me ao lado, nunca tinha pensado nisso dessa forma... Muito interessante.

Comment: @JorgeB, referes-te à questão da eufonia?

Comment: Sim Jacinto, é um ponto de vista interessante e que tem bastante lógica.

Answer (score 4):

Na idade média era essencial a unidade línguística e religiosa como forma de um país manter suas fronteiras bem definidas. Todos os governantes tentaram, em maior ou menor grau, manter a língua de seu reino livre de estrangeirismos. Os portugueses, como "donos da língua" sempre zelaram muito mais por sua integridade que os outros povos falantes, a ponto de que em certa época não se podia registrar um filho com um nome estrangeiro ou inventado.  ***E aqui, uma correção: conforme menciona @Artefacto em seu comentário, essa proibição é válida até os dias de hoje.*** Quanto a nós, brasileiros, é verdade que somos mais abertos a estrangeirismos, até nos nomes próprios. Mas, mesmo assim, no tocante às siglas, também as traduzimos.  E os exemplos são muitos: ONU, OEA, OTAN, UE, EUA, URSS, DST, TOC, UTI, IAM, DPOC, RTU, etc.

PS Não houve nenhuma intenção de sarcasmo quanto a expressão "donos da língua". Realmente, no meu ponto de vista, os portugueses, espanhóis, ingleses, franceses, etc. são os donos de línguas que outros povos "tomaram emprestada" e que em alguns casos transformaram em dialetos.

Comment: Ainda não se pode, a não ser que um dos pais seja estrangeiro. Podes ver a lista [aqui](http://www.irn.mj.pt/sections/irn/a_registral/registos-centrais/docs-da-nacionalidade/vocabulos-admitidos-e/downloadFile/file/Lista_de_nomes30-09-2015-v1.pdf?nocache=1447669882.07). Não é como vais da premissa (falsa) de sermos os donos da língua para aí. De resto, podíamos dar argumentos em sentido contrário, como uma menor tendência a aportuguesar estrangeirismos e deixá-los na forma original, o que faz com que em dados círculos cada frase tenha 2 palavras pronunciadas à inglesa.

Comment: @Artefacto  Acho que a expressão "donos da língua" foi mal compreendida.  Não houve nenhum tom de sarcasmo: os portugueses realmente são os donos da língua no sentido que todos os outros povos que a falam tomaram-na emprestada. Os ingleses e os franceses também são donos da língua falada por americanos, canadianos etc.

Comment: @Artefacto  Interessante a lista.  Encontrei, no entanto, alguns nomes tipicamente estrangeiros que são permitidos: Astrid, Barac, Brian, Elton, Franklin, etc.

Comment: Muito estranho. Creio que o que a legislação diz é que nomes estrangeiros são permitidos, desde que adaptados às regras ortográficas da língua, o que não o caso desses nomes.